# .text() not working for select form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to retrieve the value of two select fields when a button is clicked using jQuery. Here are relevant snippets of code.

I have this in an external file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#classSubmit").click(function() {
        console.log($("dept").text());
        console.log($("num").val());
    });
});
```

And this is the php script that generates one of my select statements, the second one is populated later as a result of a xmlhttp request

```
<form id="addclass">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dept">Department</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="dept">
      <?php    
      $departments = array("---",
        "ACCT", "AAS", "AMST", "ANTH", "ARAB",
        "ARCH", "ART", "ASIA", "ASTR", "BIOE",
        "BIOS", "BUS", "BIS", "CHE", "CHM",
        "CHIN", "CEE", "CLSS", "COGS", "COMM",
        "CIE", "CREG", "CSE", "CSB", "CPSY",
        "DES", "EES", "ECK", "ECO", "EDUC",
        "EDL", "ECE", "ESE", "ENGR", "EMC",
        "ENGL", "ESLP", "ENTP", "ES", "FIN",
        "FREN", "GERM", "GCP", "GS", "GBEN",
        "GBUS", "MBA", "HMS", "HEBR", "HIST",
        "ISE", "IBE", "IDEA", "IPRE", "IR",
        "ITAL", "JPNS", "JST", "JOUR", "LAT",
        "LAS", "LAW", "MGT", "MSE", "MKT",
        "MACC", "MAT", "MATH", "ME", "MECH",
        "MIL", "MLL", "MUS", "PHIL", "PHY",
        "POLS", "PMGT", "PSYC", "REL", "RUSS",
        "SCHP", "STS", "SOC", "SOAN", "SPAN",
        "SPED", "STAT", "SCM", "SDEV", "TLT",
        "TRAC", "TE", "THTR", "WGSS");

      foreach($departments as $dept) {
        $str = "<option>";
        $str .= $dept;
        $str .= "</option>";
        echo $str;
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="num">Class:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="num">
      <option>---</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="classSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Class</button>
</form>
```

When I press the `classSubmit` button I get two echos: the first of which is blank and the second of which is 'undefined'.

Any idea if there is another way to do this or if my problem is somewhere above in the code? Thanks!!

Comment: You cant do it this way. You need to append your php echo. $("#dept).append(....).

Comment: Try to always have 3 different files (html,javascript and php). Use ajax to call your php scrpt and then append the result into whatever div you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used the correct selectors for the selects. You need to use the `#` to select an element by id. Try the following:

```
$('#dept').val();
$('#num').val();
```

Quoted from W3 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-value):

*The value attribute provides a value for element. The value of an option element is the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element's text IDL attribute.*

Hopefully this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the `select` using `id` and then filter the selected option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#classSubmit").click(function() {
        console.log($("#dept > option").filter(":selected").text());
        console.log($("#num > option").filter(":selected").text());
    });
});
```

If the options doesn't have the `value` attribute you should use `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, two mistakes:

- You should write `$("#num")`
- there is no value for the only option child you provide...